# How to set frontend&backend yii2 turnkey?

Tags: php, yii2, frontend, backend

I am a newbie looking forward to set yii2 and experiment with it. 
I set a containter in proxmox with yiiframework turnkey. 
Then installed adminlte and now I am trying to get backend and frontend work.. but I can't. 
I tried with prettyUrls enabled and disabled but simply https://192.168.1.3/frontend/web/index.php or https://192.168.1.3/backend/web/index.php give me back the 404 error "The requested URL /frontend/web/index.php was not found on this server."

Everything is fresh and clean as just barely installed, except for this :

```
   'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@app/views' => '@backend/views'
                ],
            ],
        ],
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'dmstr\web\AdminLteAsset' => [
                'skin' => 'skin-blue',
                ],
            ],
    ],
```

that is the adminlte integration.. nothing that could even screwed something up.

I tried to set up a .htaccess file in the root with this inside:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and two different .htaccess files for frontend and backend....

even followed different guides like this one: https://devreadwrite.com/posts/htaccess-for-yii-2-advanced

But It seems that I do not have this frontend and backend separation but just 192.168.1.3 site...

Thanks a lot, 
Waiting for some help.

Lordcroci

Answer (score 1):

the frontend and backend are available when using the advanced template. To create a project with the advanced template you should use:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii-application
```

being yii-application the name of your project. After that you should initialize the project, using:

```
/path/to/php-bin/php /path/to/yii-application/init
```

After that, you should get the web folders and config files for both backend and frontend available, including the index.php

It's only after those steps are completed that you can change the prettyUrl in their respective config/main.php files (frontend and backend).

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I already have the project created and infact I am already using it. The turnkey already has the starting layer set in way to begin rapidly to work. 
The only thing is this one, about How to reach the backend Url.

Answer (score 1):

you can't access backend and frontend by these url you put in question
https://192.168.1.3/frontend/web/index.php or https://192.168.1.3/backend/web/index.php

use this

https://192.168.1.3/frontend/web/site/index.php or https://192.168.1.3/backend/web/site/index.php

1.first of all after installing yii2 by using this commant

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii-application
```

2.you must use init command so index file will be available to access the url. After install project just enter to project folder and open terminal and enter command

```
./init
```

and select the development option. after this the index file will be available in web folder in both backend and frontend folder.

3.Create a database with any name you want and update common/config/main-local.php file by entering the database detail.

4.Go to your project folder and run command

```
./yii migrate or yii migrate
```

it will create two table in your database name users and migrate.
after this add the htaccess file to your backend and frontend's web folder

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and enable pretty url in config file in backend and frontend and uncomment the url manager code.

5.after this you can access the backend and frontend by 
https://hostname/backend/web/site/index.php and 
https://hostname/frontend/web/site/index.php
but in the question you write this
backend/web/index.php
frontend/web/index.php
which is wrong.
Just access frontend and backend by this 
https://hostname/backend/web/site/index.php and https://hostname/frontend/web/site/index.php
and you are good to go.

Comment: ok i followed you till point 2.. the rest was already done in the turnkey (honestly even the 2 point was already done, but i just decided to try and overwrite everything) then I read the documentation of the turnkey and discovered that there is a WEBMIN so logged in and found out that in order to access the backend I should use https:192.168.1.3/admin.. now the thing is that i overwrote some page 'cause used the adminlte template and followed a guide. 

Thanks a lot!
Lordcroci